# Restart celery if celery worker is down on windows

Tags: python, windows, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I wanted to know if there is a way to restart celery worker if celery worker is down due to some error or issue, so that it can be automatically restarted programmatically.

Comment: All recent operating systems provide a facility to run a supervised service that is restarted if it fails.

Comment: @KlausD. I am using windows, so can you let me know some more details about it please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861717/how-to-detect-failure-and-auto-restart-celery-worker

Comment: @zvi, the link answers talks on Ubuntu, I am using windows.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764913/how-do-i-restart-celery-workers-gracefully).

AS you are using windows, check for the ability to run Celery as a service, such as is explained [right here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378932/how-to-create-celery-windows-service).